# Convenience methods for a DI-friendly library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm making a class library intended to be used as a nuget package. I want to make it DI-friendly and not associated with any specific container.

Let's say that the project consists of 15 classes, injected to eachother by constructor injection. How can I make the consumer register my library in an easy way? Should my library expose something like `IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesToRegister()`, or perhaps even`IList<(Type type, Lifestyle lifestyle)> GetTypesToRegister()`? How is this usually approached by library designers?

Comment: I think quickest way would be to expose extension methods for all major dependency injection frameworks.

Comment: @Fabio Sounds reasonable. The downside would be that I tie the consumers to a specific version of the frameworks?

Comment: You should definitely read [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extension methods to allow users of your package to easily register specific services and their dependencies. The IServiceCollection interface will work across various DI containers. Here's a quick example from a small side project I did a while back. The example is an extension method that allows easy registration of a Azure Storage service.

```cs
public static class AzureBlobStorageServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddAzureBlobFileStorageService(this IServiceCollection services,
            Action<AzureBlobStorageServiceConfigOptions> options)
        {
            var configOptions = new AzureBlobStorageServiceConfigOptions();
            options(configOptions);

            services.AddScoped<IFileStorageService>(sp =>
            {
                var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<AzureBlobStorageService>>();
                var connectionString = configOptions.ConnectionString ??
                                       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configOptions.ConnectionString));
                var containerName = configOptions.ContainerName ??
                                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configOptions.ContainerName));
                return new AzureBlobStorageService(logger, connectionString, containerName);
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
```

You can then register the service in an application like this

```cs
services.AddAzureBlobFileStorageService(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration["Storage:ConnectionString"];
                options.ContainerName = Configuration["Storage:ContainerName"];
            });
```

So it provides a simple way to register the service and all it's dependencies and configuration data. You can use the service normally by requesting the IFileStorageService.

Not sure if this is what you were asking about but hopefully it helps. You can look up Service Collection Extension methods in the docs and read more about the specifics.

Comment: I'm not using .NET core, but this is good as inspiration, thanks :)

Comment: What are you using? This is actually a .NET Standard library. I'm not sure if .NET Framework uses the same Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace. Are you designing this to be used with a DI container?

Comment: Oh, currently .NET framework 4.7.2. I've only used `IServiceCollection` in .NET core. But yeah, the idea is to expose something that can be easily consumed by an arbitrary IoC container like autofac, simple injector etc.

Comment: The general idea should be the same. From what I understand, .NET Framework doesn't include a built-in DI container, is that correct? If so, you would have to use a third party package like Autofac anyways. This example was used with Autofac.

Comment: Right, yep. Again, thanks for the suggestion, I will probably end up with something similar :)